# How to convert pyspark dataframe to JSON?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe and i want to convert it into list which contain JSON object.
For that i have done like below..

```
df.toJSON().collect()
```

But this operation send data to driver which is costly and take to much time to perform.And my dataframe contain millions of records.So is there any another way to do it without collect() operation which is  optimized than collect().

Below is my dataframe df:-

```
      product cost
      pen      10
      book     40
      bottle   80
      glass    55
```

and output is like below :-

```
df2 = [{product:'pen',cost:40},{product:'book',cost:40},{product:'bottle',cost:80},{product:'glass',cost:55}]
```

when i print the datatype of df2 it will be list.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create **json object** in dataframe then use `collect_list` + `create_map` + `to_json` functions.

`(or)`

To write as `json` document to the file then won't use `to_json` instead use **`.write.json()`**

---

**`Create JSON object:`**

```
df.agg(collect_list(create_map(lit("product"),"product",lit("cost"),"cost")).alias("stru")).\
selectExpr("to_json(stru) as json").\
show(10,False)

#+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|json                                                                                                                           |
#+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[{"product":"pen","cost":"10"},{"product":"book","cost":"40"},{"product":"bottle","cost":"80"},{"product":"glass","cost":"55"}]|
#+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


#write to hdfs use .saveAsTextFile
df.agg(collect_list(create_map(lit("product"),"product",lit("cost"),"cost")).alias("stru")).selectExpr("to_json(stru) as json").rdd.map(lambda x:x['json']).saveAsTextFile("<path>")

#cat part-00000
#[{"product":"pen","cost":"10"},{"product":"book","cost":"40"},{"product":"bottle","cost":"80"},{"product":"glass","cost":"55"}]
```

---

**`Create JSON file:`**

```
df.agg(collect_list(create_map(lit("product"),"product",lit("cost"),"cost")).alias("stru")).write.mode("overwrite").json("<path>")

#cat part-00000-3a19165e-219e-4485-adb8-ef91589d6e31-c000.json
#{"stru":[{"product":"pen","cost":"10"},{"product":"book","cost":"40"},{"product":"bottle","cost":"80"},{"product":"glass","cost":"55"}]}
```

Comment: I have tried this but output will be pyspark dataframe but i don't want a pyspark dataframe. i just want to convert pyspark dataframe to list which contain json object without using collect and toJSON function.... @Shu