# How to convert Jsonstring column in pyspark dataframe to jsonobject?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

I have a columnn with jsonstring in my pyspark data frame, and trying to ingest to cosmos DB. due to the string type the jsonstring is escaped with "\" cosmos db. whats the best way to convert this column type from string to json object?

dataframe column with jsonstring -

[{"Date":"11/13/2020 3:23:21 PM","Ids":"[]","col2":"abc","col3":"","value3":"[]","currency":"","status":"Active","tag":"[]","Info":"[]"}]

after migration cosmos db this value goes as

[{\"Date":\"11/13/2020 3:23:21 PM\",\"Ids\":\"[]\",\"col2\":\"abc\",\"col3\":\"\",\"value3\":\"[]",\"currency":\"\",\"status":\"Active\",\"tag":\"[]\",\"Info\":\"[]\"}]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create **json object** in data frame then use `collect_list` + `create_map` + `to_json` functions.

Here is the example for reference:

**`Create JSON object:`**

```py
df.agg(collect_list(create_map(lit("product"),"product",lit("cost"),"cost")).alias("stru")).\  
selectExpr("to_json(stru) as json").\  
show(10,False)

#+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
#|json |  
#+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
#|[{"product":"pen","cost":"10"},{"product":"book","cost":"40"},{"product":"bottle","cost":"80"},{"product":"glass","cost":"55"}]|  
#+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

#write to hdfs use .saveAsTextFile  
df.agg(collect_list(create_map(lit("product"),"product",lit("cost"),"cost")).alias("stru")).selectExpr("to_json(stru) as json").rdd.map(lambda x:x['json']).saveAsTextFile("<path>")

#cat part-00000  
#[{"product":"pen","cost":"10"},{"product":"book","cost":"40"},{"product":"bottle","cost":"80"},{"product":"glass","cost":"55"}]
```

Here is the reference [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61278832/15968720) thread

Comment: Thanks Venkatesh for the response!. My Jsonstring is having close to 30+ attributes and its hard for me to convert all properties to jsonobject in the above option. Since this jsonstring is already proper jsonobject stored as string, is there a column data type conversion available in pyspark, which can be leveraged here?. Also i have other columns(other than jsonstring) in dataframe